# How to use loop index to change variable and assign data from different dataframes

Tags: r, loops, indexing

I'm trying to use the following code to simply use the loop counter to change the day that is being assigned/stored in a new variable.

```
n.subj_FL <- 61 
n.days <- 7

for(i in 1:n.days) {# Get temporary data
  
  temp.data_More60 <- Days_Seconds_More60_PD$Seconds_More60_Day[[i]] # here I am filtering the rows according to the 'i'th individual, and then selectin the      #appropriate column with RWS information
  temp.data_3060 <- Seconds_3060[Seconds_3060$Gait_Day==n.days[i]]
  temp.data_1030 <- Seconds_10_30[Seconds_10_30$Gait_Day==n.days[i]]
  temp.data_Less10 <- Seconds_Less10[Seconds_Less10$Gait_Day==n.days[i]] 
}
```

But I keep getting an error message saying 'unitiated column'. All I want to do, is change the day of data that is being stored in the loop using [i].

Comment: Apparently you're trying to use a column that doesn't exist. Are all of your objects data frames? `Days_Seconds_More60_PD`, `Seconds_3060`, `Seconds_10_30`, `Seconds_Less10`? Are you sure are your column names are spelled correctly? Could you make a small reproducible example, maybe just 1 data frame and a few rows, showing input and desired output? `dput(Days_Seconds_More60_PD[1:10, ])` is a great way to share a copy/pasteable example of the first 10 rows of `Days_Seconds_More60_PD`, including all class and structure information.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll double check when I'm back in the office tomorrow and let yo know!!